# Android SDK , Eclipse not installing properly

Tags: android, eclipse

I just downloaded the Android SDK from this link : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ( the 64 bit version ).
Also my PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64), and I have Java SE Development Kit 8u5 installed.
The problem I am having is as it appears in this screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oadxk.png
As you can see, there are no android toolbar icons.
Also I noticed that the title bar says "Resource - ", which just doesn't seem right.

Could someone provide some assistance ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the Java perspective. Right now, you're in the Resource perspective, which since you code in Java for Android, is not the right perspective.

To fix this, go to Window -> Open Perspective -> Java.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Wonder why they set the Resource perspective as default ?